# Calculating matrix product with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network, matrix-multiplication

**Is this code segment:**

```
layer_1 = self.layer_0.dot(self.weights_0_1)
```

**The same as this one?**

```
layer_1 = np.dot(self.layer_0, self.weights_0_1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: `dot` is available both as a function in the `numpy` module and as an instance method of an `array` object.